# Fixed Position Div Centered with 100% Width

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

I have found some questions that touched on this and I have tried multiple methods to get it to work, but keep striking out so I figured I'd just post my specifics. I have a div and within it I want to center another div with a fixed position. I am able to do this with the CSS I have attached. But, the only problem I see with this is if I change my main container width then I have to update my title div width as well. I'd like to be able to use 100% width for the title div so it always matches the width of the parent container, while having a fixed position and staying centered within the div.

```
    #main-container{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:black;
    height: 100%;

}

#header{
  color: white;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left:-500px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Fixed positioning is relative to the viewport, not the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

for the #main-container try

```
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
```